# VSTS Extension - Storing parameters from build task and call a web service from summary tab

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I need to display the result of a custom build task in summary tab (“ms.vss-build-web.build-results-section”). In order to do this I need to retain some data from build task and use it to call a web service from summary section. Is it possible to store data in a variable using Extension Data Service and use it in summary page? What should be the best approach for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you call web service when build completed? Based on this sample https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer, it updates image when build completed.

Comment: I need to pass some data to summary page, I'm planning to use VSS Extension Data Service for this.

1.) Ill Save result from build task as a setting in extension data service.
2.) Ill read the setting from extension data service on summary page load and bind those values to html.

I assume this is correct approch.

Thanks-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have attached my build task data using a Logging command

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/986f8f5112017474962affe58c9ebaf394fb9354/docs/authoring/commands.md

```html
//Build Task

class TestClass {
    _name: string;
    _age: number;

    constructor(name: string, age:number) {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }
}

var data = new TestClass(TinTin,100);

//Create a folder
tl.mkdirP("c:/myfolder/");

//Write data to a file
tl.writeFile("c:/myfolder/mydata.txt",JSON.stringify(data));

//Executes command to attach the file to build
console.log("##vso[task.addattachment type=myAttachmentType;name=myAttachmentName;]c:/myfolder/mydata.txt");
```

Retrieve the attachment from summary page.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/build-results-enhancer/src/enhancer/tab.ts

```html
//Summary Page

/// <reference path="../definitions/Q.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../definitions/vss.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../definitions/tfs.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../definitions/jquery.d.ts" />

import VSS_Service = require("VSS/Service");
import Controls = require("VSS/Controls");
import TFS_Build_Contracts = require("TFS/Build/Contracts");
import TFS_Build_Extension_Contracts = require("TFS/Build/ExtensionContracts");
import DT_Client = require("TFS/DistributedTask/TaskRestClient");

export class StatusSection extends Controls.BaseControl { 
 constructor() {
  super();
 }
  
 public initialize(): void {
  super.initialize();

  // Get configuration that's shared between extension and the extension host
  var sharedConfig: TFS_Build_Extension_Contracts.IBuildResultsViewExtensionConfig = VSS.getConfiguration();
  var vsoContext = VSS.getWebContext();
  
  if(sharedConfig) {
   // register your extension with host through callback
   sharedConfig.onBuildChanged((build: TFS_Build_Contracts.Build) => {

    var taskClient = DT_Client.getClient();
    taskClient.getPlanAttachments(vsoContext.project.id, "build", build.orchestrationPlan.planId, "myAttachmentType").then((taskAttachments)=> {
           
    if (taskAttachments.length === 1) {
     var recId = taskAttachments[0].recordId;
     var timelineId = taskAttachments[0].timelineId;

     taskClient.getAttachmentContent(vsoContext.project.id, "build", build.orchestrationPlan.planId,timelineId,recId,"myAttachmentType","myAttachmentName").then((attachementContent)=> {              
      function arrayBufferToString(buffer){
         var arr = new Uint8Array(buffer);
         var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);
         if(/[\u0080-\uffff]/.test(str)){
          throw new Error("this string seems to contain (still encoded) multibytes");
         }
         return str;
        }
      
      var summaryPageData = arrayBufferToString(attachementContent);
      
      //Deserialize data
      var ob = JSON.parse(summaryPageData);
      console.log("Name: " + ob._name);
      console.log("Age: " + ob._age);

     });     
    }
    }); 
   });
  }  
 } 
}

StatusSection.enhance(StatusSection, $(".build-status"), {});

// Notify the parent frame that the host has been loaded
VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
```

Comment: Dude! I can't belie that MS didn't write the "getAttachmentContent" in their tutorials, I'l been working 2 days to solve how to get this data.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but the issue is that the those values are always the values from the latest build, the information in summary page would be incorrect for old builds. So I would recommend to the get the build task result via [BuildHttpClient2_2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/restclient/buildhttpclient2_2) and then show it in the summary page directly.

Comment: Hi Eddie,
My extension retrieves build artifacts and upload those to a web service. The web service accepts these artifacts and return some info (a summary in xml format) which I need to display in summary section.(I’m assuming need to store the xml data and load in summary html page.) But I’m not sure how to do this. As you explained user may view previous builds and he should see the respective result summary. I have analyzed samples from Microsoft but they don’t have similar samples for my problem scenario. Can you point me to any samples or documentation which help me resolve this?

Comment: @BandR Did you see this before: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/data-storage?

Comment: @Edddie, Yes Eddie I have considered this option, the issue is if I use the extension data service, I have to manually manage those documents created in data storage. I’m looking the simplest possible way to do this avoiding ext data service :). I have noticed that TFS_Build_Contracts.Build object contains build related information. Is there a way to persist my task output (the xml I mentioned) as an object somewhere inside the build contract so that I can retrieve it from summary page? or any other better option?

Comment: @BandR No, there isn't any way to change update the TFS_Build_Contracts.Build object. I'm not sure what information the web service return. But if possible, I would recommend you to generate these information during the build process and store them in build logs. Then you will be easy to get them in extension.

Comment: Thanks Eddie, It seems I can retrieve a BuildLogReference object with a url to log resource. Can you point me to any developer sample codes how to do this?

Comment: @BandR I'm sorry I didn't get you. What do you mean retrieve a BuildLogReference object with a url to log resource?

Comment: I gt suggestion frm another source, which is by using logging commands(You also mentioned ths in earlier answer). They have suggested to upload data as an attachment from vsts-tasks logging command and retrieve from summary page using "TFS/DistributedTask/TaskRestClient". However I could not find a better example on how to attach the file. Will you be able to guide me on this?
[Attach](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)
[Retrieve](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/blob/master/build-results-enhancer/src/enhancer/tab.ts#L25)

Comment: @BandR It's "##vso[task.addattachment]value", "##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path", "##vso[task.uploadfile]local file path" command, you can create a powershell script in your build definition and use these commands in the powershell script. Refer to this link for details: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

Comment: In order to do this, first I have to write data to disk? then use power shell command to attach the file? Is it possible to execute this command from typescript code using vsts-task library? If so, can you point me to a dev sample. - Thanks

Comment: @BandR Yes, you need to write data to a file in the disk and then upload it. The command is invoked via standard output. So for typescript, the same as powershell script, you just need to write out the command to build console during the build process.

Comment: I have managed to transfer data from build task to summary page as an attachment. I have replied to my questions with sample code. I hope VSTS team will provide better api support for this in future. :) Thanks.