# Team Services - Display link to easily download installer created

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We're using Team Services and we have a batch file that creates an installer (MSI and exe) using WIX.
After the installer is successfully created, inside the same batch file we're moving it to a new server.

Now, what I want to achieve is to publish a link in the VSTS build results to be able to easily download the installer created. This way it's easier for stakeholders to get it, rather that remoting into the server containing the installer and copying it from there.

Something like //192.168.0.1//Path_to_the_build/installerName.exe

Whoever needs it, just clicks that link and the download starts on his machine.

Is this possible to have it displayed in the build results?

Comment: The artifacts can be published to your server (Select File Share artifact type for publish artifact step/task), I updated my answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [build artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts)? Then you can download it directly:

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the artifacts are uploaded to VS Team Services. I'd wanna avoid upload a couple tens on MB for each build run. Especially since the plan is to have this builder running on a nightly basis. That's why I was trying to just get the URL meaning the location of the installer.

Comment: You can select what file(s) to include using the Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) step. Default is all files in release folders - however you can select only specific files.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish artifacts to your server (not VSTS server) by selecting File Share (not Server) Artifact type and specify a shared folder path (need to be accessible from build server).

After that, you can click Explore link to get the detail URL or download:

[image]

Note: Your server may not accessible from Hosted Agent, you can setup a private agent on your server:

[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Another way is that you can do it by using build result extension.

There is the sample of build results extension: [build-results-enhancer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer).

To learn VSTS extension, you can refer to: [Write your first extension for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node)

On the other hand, this thread may benefit you: [VSTS Extension - Storing parameters from build task and call a web service from summary tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031367/vsts-extension-storing-parameters-from-build-task-and-call-a-web-service-from)